# Can I use the find command to create links in subdirectories based on filenames?

Tags: linux

(Linux newbie here)

I have a directory containing a master file 'cs010101.SETUP' and a number of sub-directories. Each sub-directory contains a large number of files including some of the format cs??????.dat3.  I'm looking for a way to find all the cs??????.dat3 files and then for each, in its corresponding directory, create a soft link back to the master file (cs010101.SETUP) with the six digit number changed to the match the respective cs??????.dat3 file.

*e.g* If a sub-directory contains the file cs219254.dat3, I want to perform the command

```
ln -s ../cs010101.SETUP cs219254.SETUP
```

So far I've got as far as the find command

```
find . -name "cs*dat3"
```

and looked at piping to cut in order to extract the number

```
find . -name "cs*dat3" | cut -c 13-18
```

(this works currently as the naming convention for the sub-directories is consistent, though would be nice if didn't have to rely on that fact).

But now I'm stumped!

Comment: You could first pipe through `| while read f; do basename $f .dat3; done |`, which will output just the `cs######` portion of the names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sed. Script may look like this:

```sh
for dname in `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*" -type d`; do #list all subdirectories of this directory only
    for fnum in `find $dname -name "cs*.dat3" | sed 's/^.*cs\([0-9]*\)\.dat3$/\1/'`; do #extract numbers of needed files in subdir
        ln -s $PWD/cs010101.SETUP $dname/cs$fnum.SETUP #create link
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you.  Just what I was after.  One small issue is that it also seems to create a link for each file in the parent directory as well as the appropriate subdirectory.  Not a huge issue as it's easily handled with an 'rm' for the unwanted links, but I just can't see what in your script causes this!

Comment: Have answered my own question.  The first time through your loop it finds all the files in both the parent directory and all sub-directories and creates links in the parent directory.  It then operates on each sub-directory in turn.  Including a -mindepth 1has fixed this so it only looks in the sub-directories, which is the behavior I was after.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought...  CSH (aka TCSH) offers various ":" options on variables - e.g.:

```
% set a = ./b/bb/cs219255.dat3

% echo $a:h
./b/bb

% echo $a:t
cs219255.dat3

% echo $a:r
./b/bb/cs219255

% echo $a:e
dat3
```

Do you want absolute paths or relative paths?

```
foreach T ( `find . -name 'cs*dat3' -print` )
foreach? ln -s `pwd`/cs010101.SETUP  $T:r.SETUP-absolutepath
foreach? ln -s `echo $T:h | sed 's|/[^/]*|/..|g'`/cs010101.SETUP $T:r.SETUP-relativepath
foreach? end
```

Caveat:  We should probably use + instead of * in the sed expression, e.g. sed 's|/[^/]+|/..|g'.  But I was testing this on a very limited system with a broken version of sed.  *sigh*.

Comment: That should be \+ -- Looks like something ate my backslash